# Fixed-width or fluid-width for accessibility

Tags: css, accessibility, fixed-width, fluid-layout

I was told that fixed-width websites are not accessible because most screen readers cannot read content that scrolls off the screen.  Is there any truth to this?  This doesn't sound correct to me, so I thought I would ask for some clarification on the topic.  Any information would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen readers *can* read content regardless of whether or not it is within view.

The generally accepted rule is that fluid width layouts are more accessible because the content will flex to whatever size the client's device can support, rather than guess at the width.